# How can I get BEST Video chat quality- Wowza, Red5, FMS, LCCS(Cirrus)?

Tags: flash-media-server, rtmp, wowza, rtmfp

I am developing a P2P video chat commercial application.

I will have small business users from different parts of the world using this software with varying internet speed and varying P2P geographical distance.

- Which  of the following design will give me BEST (as good as or better than skype) video chat quality?

a) RTMP and Wowza, FMS or Red5 media server?
b) LCCS paid offerring using RTMFP and RTMP (for failover)

Answer (score 0):

RTMP is not a P2P protocol. All the traffic will pass via your server. 
Hence the only viable solution in the P2P case is using Cirrus (which should now be available in the latest FMS server).
As for the video quality - you can change it in your flash application (the using Camera's setQuality method) according to the user's bandwidth.